# multiple xmp versions of same raw file?

Tags: raw, xmp

I've come to the inescapable conclusion that RAW is the way to go and I've run into a small problem. I know this can be done, but I can't remember how.

I want to save different versions of the raw output- f'r instance one in color and one in BW, but I want to save them in the RAW format with 2 different sidecar iterations-not PSD or TIF. How might I do that?

(I'll probably kick myself once I get the answer...)

Thanks!
marc

ps- in a different thread I saw this comment from Blrfl saying "many programs will allow you to develop multiple versions of the same original image by storing the changes in multiple sidecars." So it appears quite possible! my fingers are crossed!

Comment: What software are you using, or do you want to use? Or will you use any software that will provide this functionality?

Comment: I'm using Photoshop and learned about the "Snapshot" function in Adobe Raw which settled the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store them in sidecars specifically?

If Adobe Lightroom is an option for you, this software is purpose-built for this sort of scenario.

You can create multiple "virtual copies" of the same image in the Lightroom library, and develop them in different ways.

The settings are not stored in multiple sidecar files, but it's unclear what your workflow is that would require raws with multiple sidecars rather than e.g. exporting a PSD or TIF from the appropriate virtual copy for downstream editing.

Comment: It's not that I wanted multiple sidecars, but that I thought it was the only way to have multiple versions of a raw file without duplicating the nef file. It turns out that Photoshop does indeed have the ability to have multiple versions of a single file using the "Snapshot" function in Adobe Raw (the last tab in ACR) which settled the issue.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using darktable, then select the image in lighttable mode and push 'duplicate'. The button can be found under the 'selected images' control group.

[Relevant User Manual Page](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch02s03s06.html.php)

Comment: I'm using Photoshop, thank you, and I found a solution using using the "Snapshot" function in Adobe Raw (the last tab in ACR).
I appreciate your help. Thanks!